# Check if user clicked the checkbox

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

On QWEB `Invoice Portal` I wanna check if user have checked the checkbox, if checked show the buttons else hide them.

I create a field on `Invoice` model: `x_custom_checkbox: bool`

`Default state: False`

When the state of `x_custom_checkbox = False`

[image]

When the state of `x_custom_checkbox = True`

[image]

On view `Invoice Portal Template` I use `<input type="checkbox" id="invoice.x_custom_checkbox"/>` to call the field, who can dynamically show/hide the 2 buttons (above image) according the state of checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is actual very simple after some testings
on `Invoice Portal` xml

```
 <center><input id="checkbox-status" type="checkbox" name="invoice.x_custom_checkbox"/> Accept</center>

 <div id="ShowHideDiv" class="o_download_pdf btn-toolbar flex-sm-nowrap">

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#ShowHideDiv").hide();
            $("#checkbox-status").change(function() {
                if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    $("#ShowHideDiv").show();
                } else {
                    $("#ShowHideDiv").hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this on js.

```
odoo.define('your_module_name.account_portal_sidebar', function (require) {
'use strict';

    var AccountPortalSidebar = require('account.AccountPortalSidebar');

    AccountPortalSidebar.include({

            events: _.extend({
                'change input#x_custom_checkbox': '_onXCustomCheckboxChange',
            }, AccountPortalSidebar.prototype.events),

    _onXCustomCheckboxChange: function () {
                var self = this;
                var x_custom_checkbox_checked = this.$('input#x_custom_checkbox').prop('checked');
                if (x_custom_checkbox_checked){
                    $('.o_download_btn').show();
                    $('.o_portal_invoice_print').show();
                } else {
                    $('.o_download_btn').hide();
                    $('.o_portal_invoice_print').hide();
                }
           }, // end of _onXCustomCheckboxChange
});
```